# Multivariable Non-degenerate Critical Points Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^2$ function, and the origin is a non-degenerate critical point and suppose $f(x,mx)$ is a local minimum at the origin for all $m$, then does $f$ have a local minimum at the origin?

I understand that if the function is not degenerate, then we either have a local maximum (which we can rule out, since the function has local minimums as you approach the origin via a straight line), a local minimum, or a saddle point.

I am not sure how to rule out that it's not a saddle point. In particular, I'm not sure how you apply the non-degenerate condition rigorously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ has a saddle point at $(0,0)$. Let $v\in\Bbb R^2$ be an eigenvector of the Hessian of $f$ at $(0,0)$ such that the corresponding eigenvalue $\mu$ is negative; $v$ must exist, since $(0,0)$ is a non-degenerate critical point. Consider the map $\varphi\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $\lambda\mapsto f(\lambda v)$. Then $\varphi'(0)=0$ (since $(0,0)$ is a critical point of $f$), and $\varphi''(0)<0$ (since $\mu<0$). Therefore, $0$ is a local *maximum* of $\varphi$.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Just wanted to clarify, when you say that 0 is a local maximum of $\phi$, I'm assuming you're trying to create the contradiction that I have already ruled out that 0 is a local max for $f$. But I do not see how this follows. If $x$ is a local max of $\varphi (\lambda)$ why does it follow that $x$ is a local max of $f(\lambda v)$? We are restricting the input to $f$ to be along a particular line, namely $\lambda v$. Couldn't there be a point $x$ in the vicinity of the origin that is not on this particular line such that $f(x) > f(0)$?

Comment: Never mind, it contradicts with the fact that $f$ has a local minimum for all lines approaching the origin. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that you've answered your question before I had to type an answer myself. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes very helpful indeed. Done!